# IServiceProvider with a restriction on the Type the user can ask the provider for

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

[`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=net-6.0) has a single method [`public object? GetService (Type serviceType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider.getservice?view=net-6.0#system-iserviceprovider-getservice(system-type)).

Is there a language construct to restrict the `Type serviceType` argument to only things that implement a certain `IMarker` interface (which has no methods, only serves as a marker for API discoverability).

Kind of like this (but this obviously doesn't compile):

```cs
public interface IMarker { }

public class SvcProvider : IServiceProvider {
  public object? GetService(Type serviceType) where Type : IMarker {
    
  }
}
```

---

I tried [phrasing this question differently here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412086/c-sharp-factory-constraints-on-return-type?noredirect=1#comment127922031_72412086), but got into some trouble with people understanding what I was trying to achieve.

---

#### Updated code for comments discussion:

Same snippet of dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yXNq8K

```cs
public interface IMarker {}

public class Impl1 : IMarker {}

public class Program
{
    //Compiles Ok
    public static T? GetServiceDefaultConstruct<T>() where T : IMarker, new() {
        return new T();
    }
    
    // Doesn't compile, says that T can be a non-nullable value type.
    public static T? GetServiceNull<T>() where T : IMarker {
        return null;
    }
    
    // Compiles Ok
    public static T? GetServiceNullExplicitConstraint<T>() where T : class,IMarker {
        return null;
    }
    
    // Doesn't compile: "Can not convert Impl1 to T"
    public static T? GetService<T>() where T : class,IMarker {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Impl1))
            return new Impl1();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `IServiceProvider`'s desing is a rather blunt instrument - what problem are you _really_ trying to solve?

Comment: The problem you run into now is that you're dealing with an existing interface, whereas your previous post's `Create<T>` method could have its own constraints, which would've allowed you to return `new T()` and move on. The best you're going to get is a *runtime contraint*, which means no support at the language level, and throwing something like `InvalidOperationException` if `T` doesn't satisfy the restrictions you wish to impose. If you hadn't asked about a language construct, that might meet your needs.

Comment: @Dai The actual problem: I have different kinds of readers for different purposes. A single data source (e.g. a file or a database) can provide multiple data streams. Let's say I have Images and Text. And I will have ImageReader1, ImageReader2 (for different image formats) and a TextReader1. Now for the users of the API I would like to provide a single entry point - `DataSourceFactory`. The factory is initialized with a location of the actual data (e.g. a DB connection string or a file path). I would like to have methods for the user to query the factory for:... -to-be-continued-

Comment: @Dai -continued-here- to query the factory for: 1) types of services available with this data source connected 2) how many services of each type are there (there might be multiple images, for example). 3) to get the actual implementations to get the data from the source.

Comment: @madreflection Following your advice I tried to reformulate the question here. And that's why I didn't use `IServiceProvider` in my previous question/example. I'm not cosntrained to `IServiceProvider`, I can roll my own. But I also don't want to impose a `: new()` constraint. I will figure out myself how to create the types the user has asked for, all I want is to have a constraint to hint the user at what they're allowed to ask for. E.g. it doesn't make sense for the user to ask for an `IList` or other stuff. The user should get a hint that they should be asking for stuff marked with IMarker

Comment: What's the reason for not constraining to `new()`? Is it because you need constructor parameters? Or is there some other intent behind it?

Comment: @madreflection Not constraining to `new()` because in the original formulation using it hides the core of the question. Yes it does work with `new()`. But I have services that I can't just default-create.

Comment: @madreflection I strongly dislike the `new()` constraint because it means you can't use well-designed types (where parameterized ctors enforce class invariants or make state guarantees) for type-arguments. It's much better to just accept a `Func<T>` factory instead of requiring `new()`.

Comment: @Dai: Understandable. I'm just trying to get OP to separate the real roadblocks from the artificial ones. Considering that non-default constructors are involved, it's now clear that it's real and not self-imposed.

Comment: The previous post only had default construction; no incomplete invariants indicated. It was an error of oversimplification, something that I opine has happened on multiple levels. I wouldn't have made the suggestion that led to this second question if I had known what I know now about how deep it goes (and doubt enough has been revealed even still).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# factory - constraints on return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412086/c-sharp-factory-constraints-on-return-type)

Comment: @KenWhite you just linked to the other version of the same question that I posted earlier and also linked to at the end of this question. It also doesn't have any answers.

Comment: Yes, I have, because the proper conduct here when you don't get answers to a question is to edit the question to improve it, not to post a duplicate question. You should review the [help] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite Well, thank you kind sir. Have you found these two questions yourself because they were so similar or did you just follow the backlink I posted here myself? Did you take any time to compare the questions really?

Comment: it's unclear on why you don't need a generic version of the method (so it will be like this `GetService<T>() where T : IMarker` instead of using the non-generic version. All non-generic code may be used more with reflection.

Comment: @KingKing That's exactly how I tried to do it. `T? GetService<T>() where T:IMarker`. But the compiler won't let me return instances of implementations. `T? GetService<T>() where T:IMarker { if (typeof(T) == typeof(Impl1) return new Impl1();  }` doesn't compile - says it `can't convert Impl1 to T?`

Comment: @DmitryAvtonomov that does not make sense to me, if your instance type implements the service type (`T`), you can return that instance normally (completely valid). Looks like you should update your question with that approaching of writing the generic method together with that strange error you have.

Comment: @KingKing I added a code sample to the question. Also, here's that same snippet on dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yXNq8K

Comment: @DmitryAvtonomov `Impl1` and `T` both implements `IMarker` but there is no constraint to ensure that `Impl1` can be converted to `T`. The compiler complains correctly. Because you already check the `T` type before, you can always cast the `Impl1` to `T` like this `return (T) new Impl1();`

Comment: @DmitryAvtonomov actually `return (T) new Impl1()` also does not work, you need to cast it to `object` first before casting to `T`, like `return (T) (object) new Impl1()`, see the modified working demo here https://dotnetfiddle.net/d7e6B1

Comment: @KingKing Thank you! I've also found that instead of casting twice `return new Impl1() as T` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

```cs
interface IMarker { }

interface ISvcProvider {
  public T? GetService<T>() where T: class, IMarker;
}

class SvcProviderImpl : ISvcProvider {
  public T? GetService<T>() where T: class, IMarker {
    // example of some logic for possible implementations 
    if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SpecificType))) {
      SpecificType impl = new(); // or obtain it some other way
      return impl as T;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```